# How to parse GMT timezone Golang

Tags: go, timezone

I have time zone id like this: `(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris`. What is the best way to get `time.Location` from this string?

Comment: That's not a time, that's a location description. Do you have a full date/time string you want to parse, or just the location from this string?

Comment: @Marc just location

Comment: `time.FixedZone` might be the option for you, which returns `time.Location` when called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to extract the zone name from your string, then turn it into a location.

You can do the first part using regexps, the latter with [time.LoadLocation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`^\(([A-Z]+)[+-:0-9]+\).*`)
    input := "(GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris."

    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(input)
    fmt.Println("Found timezone string: ", matches[1])

    l, _ := time.LoadLocation(matches[1])
    fmt.Println("Found timezone:", l)

    fmt.Println(time.Now())
    fmt.Println(time.Now().In(l))
}
```

This prints out:

```
$ go run ./main.go
Found timezone string:  GMT
Found timezone: GMT
2018-01-24 10:30:28.989832073 +0100 CET
2018-01-24 09:30:28.989860913 +0000 GMT
```

**warning**: I'm ignoring errors and non-matching regexp, you probably shouldn't.